# Two contemporary Forms in Windows Mobile

Tags: c#, forms, windows-mobile, compact-framework

Is possible to display two forms using the Compact Framework (Windows Mobile 6.1), where the first form (behind the second - GREEN) occupies the entire space (as default), while the second form (above the first - BLUE) has a distance greater than zero from the top of the screen (a Top property that does not work when I tried it)?

The following image explains what I mean:

[image]

How can I do?

Comment: Did you tried anything so far? Please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: Why not just use one form and add two controls one on top of the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Mobile is not capable of displaying forms that do not take the entire screen. If you need that, you must find a device that runs Windows CE. The only thing in Windows Mobile that's not "full screen" is a `MessageBox`.

As Compact Framework applications can run both on Windows Mobile and Windows CE, there is a `Top` property for forms, which has no effect in Windows Mobile (like the other properties that usually adjust location or size).

Comment: This answer is correct; however, if you must do what you are describing using WinMobile, then have one form with multiple panels. Threat the panels as forms, positioning them as needed and placing all of your controls inside of them.

Answer (score 0):

Although I also thought that sizeable windows forms are not supported, I found a simple way: http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2012/11/07/mobile-development-move-your-form/

So let us know, if this works for you.

And the rest keep on learning doing the impossible as I do all the days.